# to solve simple python list iteration

Tags: python, list

```
seq1 = ['1', '2', '3']
seq2 = ['1', '2']

for elt1 in seq1:
    for elt2 in seq2:
        if elt1 == elt2:
            seq1.remove(i)
print seq1
```

I want to leave `seq1 = ['3']`
but I find the result out `seq1 = ['2', '3']` when I use this code.

I know how to solve it by changing this code. 
I just want to know why my code does not work. 
what is actually happening in the loop?

My analysis is:

The problem is number `2` in `seq1`  does not iterate . 
Only `'1'`, `'3'` iterate. 
So in the end, the result comes out `['2', '3']`
(if it iterates on `2` in `seq1` then the result will be `['3']`)

Comment: You are iterating over a list while changing the lists' size (by removing from it). This is the source of your bugs.

Comment: Iterate in reverse, with the appropriate condition, or use a list comprehension: `t = set(lst2); lst1 = [x for x in lst1 if x not in t]`

Comment: _"I know how to solve it by changing this code. I just want to know why my code does not work."_ I just can't understand this at all...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i got it thank you ^------------------------^

Comment: @AGNGazer it means i know another answer.

Comment: @coldspeed thank you for your concern